# How to read HTTP status of the response in the jaxrs-cxf-client generated by Swagger Codegen?

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm working with a client of a REST API specified through OpenAPI on SwaggerHub. Here I read something like this:

```yaml
    put:
      tags:
        - load
      summary: adds a Demand item
      operationId: addDemandItem
      description: Adds a Demand item to the system
      security:
        - basicAuth: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: item correctly saved
        '401':
          description: 'unauthorized'
        '400':
          description: 'invalid input, object invalid'
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: partnerReferenceId
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
          description: partnerReferenceId identifying the demand
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/DemandItem'
        description: Demand item to add
```

The auto-generated client (jaxrs-cxf-client) has the following Java code:

```java
    @PUT
    @Path(value = "/demands/{partnerReferenceId}")
    @Consumes(value = {"application/json"})
    @Operation(summary = "adds a Demand item", tags = {})
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "item correctly saved"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "invalid input, object invalid"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "unauthorized")})
    public void addDemandItem(@PathParam(value = "partnerReferenceId") String string, DemandItem di);
```

How can I read the HTTP status of the response?

Comment: This is server code not client code. Make sure you're using the correct codegen (e.g. `java` if you use Swagger Codegen).

Comment: @Helen, I understand your doubt, but this is the jaxrs-cxf-client exported. Anyway `addDemandItem` returns `void` not `Response`, then how to read HTTP Status?

Comment: You might need to run the codegen with the `useGenericResponse` argument. E.g. `-DuseGenericResponse=true` if you run codegen from command line; or if you export from SwaggerHub, this option can be set in Export > Codegen Options (assuming you have edit access to the API in question). This will use `Response` as the return type for all methods.

Comment: @Helen before reading your excellent suggestion, I was thinking of a possible particular exception thrown in cases other than 200 or, at least, a generic exception, but with a structured message. I was wrong?